# Need information about the storage of my VPS

Tags: linux, docker, storage, vps

I use MobaXTerm to connect to my VPS using both SSH and FTP. Thanks to the software I also see the use of RAM/Storage/... of my VPS. By connecting I realize that I use 89% of the **40GB** of my offer. So I decided to take the one above at **50GB**. However once the change was made I only went down to **86%** usage.

I would therefore like to succeed in understanding how to control the storage of my VPS and know where I am currently.

Here is the output of the `df -h` command. Unfortunately I don't really understand why `/dev/sda1` only has **29GB**. I don't really understand if in total I still have space or not on the **50GB**.
Namely that I use pterodactyl and therefore docker.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           833M  1.9M  831M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        29G   25G  4.1G  86% /
tmpfs           4.1G     0  4.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d91d2cdb11bba83a6cb763e8e8d1474466935efc7fc6a5c6e244473c3f7d4abf/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3855868f555c118fbbbd10fe22d921ad08fc746f78f2a1e97614301d63a2cd80/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/1818aecc365ee3aa3f892fbbaa3a155d2dbacc6c185fcbc7ba5fd7bfb7fd3545/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ead54eca740041d908bbd22f797511ea8e8797831248258cc39e78c035b7694b/merged
tmpfs           833M  4.0K  833M   1% /run/user/0
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6be77edc9f670b93f76ee85d151d1d48b9b7f067234ba7d3a9ac5d0c4642aea6/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/410c022362208240b7bfb6958ca96ccd404a56566bd52eb95b2df5f0b63f38c0/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ba40f77a29e78b056712cda937087d3ed57cdbd099e59e75e72faed06fb8e837/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f06902a97c9085d196515c34809e65a14444c68058f377c5588e7e01c2e42b41/merged
overlay          29G   25G  4.1G  86% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d86b05e4c30cd7518a6e0cfc1a84cf521819f1aca0c38ef4cd7d6b4c393724c9/merged
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to look at is `/dev/sda1` which has only 4.1 gb available out of the 29 total.

```
Filesystem|Total Size|Used|Available|Use%|MountPoint
/dev/sda1      29G    25G    4.1G    86%      /
                              ^
                              |
                             this is what you need to look at
```

If your provider told you that you have 50 gb on your server they either scammed you or forgot to give you 20 gb